# Java Swing object as the key of the map

Tags: java, swing, dictionary, key

I want to use JCheckBox as the key of the map.

```
Map<JCheckBox, MyObject> checkboxToObjectMaping;
```

Is it a good idea?

Comment: what purpose do you have behind this to implement ? @Benas ?? please clearify. Any Map class use a hashing technique to add a key into a HashMap Object. So, please be specific what you asked.Thanks

Comment: Yes. This should be fine. The important thing to keep in mind is that the keys hashCode/equals doesn't depend on mutable state of the object, and JCheckBox inherits its hashCode/equals from Object, so you should be fine.